# C# - How do I sort a DataTable by date

Tags: c#, date, datatable

I have a datatable that has a date column, but I am stumped as to how to sort it by that column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
DataView view = DataTable.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "DateColumn";
```

Comment: That seems to sort it like a text field and not a date

Comment: Yes it was...I changed it to DateTime

Comment: It seems view.sort takes the date as a string. Bug in implementation by MS?