# How to sort and order merged DataSets

Tags: c#, sorting, dataset

I have 2 DataSets as shown below and I need  to merge these DataSets into 1:

dataset1

```
date              reason     total
12 aug 2010       inactive    123
19 aug 2010       inactive    45
20 sep 2010       inactive    145
02 nov 2010       inactive    95
25 dec 2010       inactive    44
```

dataset2

```
date              reason     total
12 aug 2010       active    12
21 aug 2010       active    45
20 sep 2010       active    45
02 nov 2010       active    45
26 dec 2010       active    45
```

I can merge the DataSets by using the `Merge` method, but how do I sort the DataSets to get the result like this:

```
date              reason     total
12 aug 2010       inactive     123
12 aug 2010       active       12
19 aug 2010       inactive     45
21 aug 2010       active       45
20 sep 2010       inactive    145
20 sep 2010       active      45
02 nov 2010       inactive    95
02 nov 2010       active      45
25 dec 2010       inactive    44
26 dec 2010       active      45
```

Comment: What is data type of date column? text or date? If it is date see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513961/c-sharp-how-do-i-sort-a-datatable-by-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want it in ascending date order and reason descending order, you can use a DataView's Sort property ([DataView.Sort Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx)):

```
// Assuming the merged table is the first and only table in the DataSet.
DataView dv = new DataView(dataSet1.Tables[0]);

dv.Sort = "date, reason DESC";
```

I haven't tested this - just off the top of my head.  Should point you in the right direction though.